Can a ring of finite Krull dimension be isomorphic to a non-trivial quotient of itself?
I have a question out of curiosity: Can a ring of finite Krull dimension be isomorphic to a non-trivial quotient of itself? (It seems classical so that it should be answered somewhere, but I haven't found it.)
My thoughts: If $R$ is an integral domain, then this is false. Indeed if $R\cong R/p$, then $p$ must be a prime ideal, and $\dim(R)>\dim(R/p)$, giving a contradiction. But in general case can we prove this is impossible, or are there any examples?
Edit: Thanks to @Sassatelli Giulio, if we get rid of the finite Krull dimensional condition there are indeed examples, for example:
$$ R:=k[x_1,\dots,x_n,\dots] , \quad R/I:=k[x_1,\dots,x_n,\dots]/(x_1)$$

Being isomorphism forces equal cardinality. When can a ring have same cardinality with its quotient?

@QiaochuYuan Thank you for the correction!

@QiaochuYuan Sorry but I am still a little confused. In my proof I mean the dimension of $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ (for a general ring), so I add the condition of integral domain to make it easy to prove. So if $R$ is not an integral domain, does the dimensional argument still work?

@Zoudelong: that is not what "dimension of a ring" or "finite-dimensional" means without further elaboration, and you also didn't specify commutative rings. You're referring to the Krull dimension, and in that case, yes, the integral domain condition is relevant and I don't know what happens without it.

@QiaochuYuan Thank you very much!

I have edited and voted to reopen, as neither of the marked dupe questions answers what OP's question was (as they clarified in the comments)

@AtticusStonestrom Thank you :-)

Take a field $F$, and $R=F[x_1, x_2, \cdots]/\langle x_ix_j|_{i,j=1}^{\infty}\rangle$
Note that we have $\overline{x_i}\cdot \overline{x_j}=0$ in $R$, for all $i, j$, possibly with $i=j$. Therefore $\overline{x_i}$'s are all nilpotent, so must be contained in any prime ideal. From here, it's easy to see that $R$ has a unique prime ideal that is spanned by $\overline{x_i}$'s. So $R$ has Krull dimension $0$.
Isn't it obvious $R$ has a nontrivial ideal $I$ such that $R\approx R/I$? In fact, there are infinitely many such $I$'s.

Thank you! Just to confirm, for example, we may again take $I=\left\langle \bar{x_1}\right\rangle$? :-)

Yeah, in fact any subset $\emptyset\not=S\subset \mathbb N:={1, 2, \cdots}$ with $|\mathbb N\setminus S|=\infty$ can produce a $I=\langle {\overline{x_i}}_{i\in S}\rangle$ that gets the job done.
